# HLS stream lags on iPad1 (on iPad2 plays normaly)

Tags: c++, ios, http-live-streaming

We have our own implementation of HLS Streaming server, but when we test it's streams on real devices, there is one problem. On iPad2 it looks good.  On iPad1, most of time, it looks similar as on iPad2[image]

But sometimes, it lags, and looks like: [image] for some seconds. Which video settings may make iPad1 to show video in such way, when on iPad 2 it works well? In what way I need to think at first?

Comment: Have you tried a full restore to both devices?

Comment: You mean restore firmware? How it can help?

Comment: 1. Get rid of various sludge on device, 2. Resets all settings. Also, another problem might be that the iPad 1 is just going to do that. After all, it **is** three years old. An eternity in computer time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, which I can say with nearly 100% certainty, is that the original iPad is running a processor with roughly 40% of the graphics power of the processor in the iPad 2. Thus, the original iPad wil always lag when playing large (or even small) video files.